# head_title drupal

Tags: theming

in html.html.twig in title tags

```
{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}
```

- This code display " home | " how to remove( | ) from display in home page?
- also in other page display " page | Home " i want title in other page display "Home | page " ?

Comment: In your second example "page | Home", is 'Home' meant to be the name of the website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier and better to override this using the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

The D8 version UI looks different than the picture below which is from D7.

[This video](https://youtu.be/4pYFS4Z23fg?t=3m13s) goes over the D8 version.

[image]